# UniversalImageLoader android : Add white border around rounded image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I use UniversalImageLoader library to create a rounded imageview :

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(2000))
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .build();

            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(avatar, rounded, options);
```

How can i add a thin border (1dp) around the rounded imageView ?

Comment: you can add inside imageview which is in xml

Answer (score 4):

This [issue](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/506) was addressed some times ago but was not implemented in the `UIL` so here is what you have to do  change the `BitmapDisplayer` to `CircleBitmapDisplayer` like this

```
package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.Log;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.LoadedFrom;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageAware;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageViewAware;

public class CircleBitmapDisplayer implements BitmapDisplayer {
    private float radius, centerX, centerY, borderWidth = 0;
    private int borderColor = Color.BLACK;
    private boolean biggestCircle = false, isCentered = true;

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer() {
        this.biggestCircle = true;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float centerX, float centerY) {
        this();
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.isCentered = false;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float borderWidth, int borderColor) {
        this();
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float radius, float borderWidth,
            int borderColor) {
        this(radius);
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float radius, float centerX, float centerY) {
        this(radius);
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
        this.isCentered = false;
    }

    public CircleBitmapDisplayer(float radius, float centerX, float centerY,
            float borderWidth, int borderColor) {
        this(radius, centerX, centerY);
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void display(Bitmap bitmap, ImageAware imageAware,
            LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
        if (!(imageAware instanceof ImageViewAware)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "ImageAware should wrap ImageView. ImageViewAware is expected.");
        }
        int ivWidth = imageAware.getWidth();
        int ivHeight = imageAware.getHeight();
        int bmWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int bmHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        if (isCentered) {
            centerX = (float) ivWidth / 2;
            centerY = (float) ivHeight / 2;
        }
        if (biggestCircle) {
            if (isCentered) {
                radius = ivWidth < ivHeight ? (float) ivWidth / 2
                        : (float) ivHeight / 2;
            } else {
                radius = Math.min(centerX < ivWidth - centerX ? centerX
                        : ivWidth - centerX,
                        centerY < ivHeight - centerY ? centerX : ivHeight
                                - centerY);
            }
        }
        Rect srcRect;
        if (bmWidth < bmHeight) {
            srcRect = new Rect(0, (bmHeight - bmWidth) / 2, bmWidth, bmWidth
                    + (bmHeight - bmWidth) / 2);
        } else {
            srcRect = new Rect((bmWidth - bmHeight) / 2, 0, bmHeight
                    + (bmWidth - bmHeight) / 2, bmHeight);
        }
        RectF destRectF = new RectF(0, 0, ivWidth, ivHeight);
        imageAware.setImageBitmap(getCircledBitmap(bitmap, centerX, centerY,
                radius, srcRect, destRectF, ivWidth, ivHeight, borderWidth,
                borderColor));

    }

    public static Bitmap getCircledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float centerX,
            float centerY, float radius, Rect srcRect, RectF destRectF,
            int width, int height, float borderWidth, int borderColor) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        // if 1 pixel is missing, do: radius - borderWidth + 1
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius - borderWidth, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, destRectF, paint);
        if (0 < borderWidth) {
            paint.setXfermode(null);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(borderColor);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
            canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius - borderWidth / 2, paint);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess such customization may not be offered by UniversalImageLoader Internally, however this work arround can fit your need:

The Imageview on which you wish to show the downloaded image, just set its background property to white color, and also set its padding attribute to 1DP. Then set its SRC property to the image you have downloaded using UniversalImageLoader.

This should do the trick!